# How to compute the centroid of a mesh with triangular faces?

Tags: python, c++, math, 3d, mesh

I want to compute a new centroid for my meshes given the following description. But I do not want to use Blender's built-in functions for computing centroids as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin) as it seems that they do not give me the kind of centroid I expect to get. First, I want to compute the centers of faces (triangle) of a mesh centroid of a mesh. Then I need to compute the faces area. The new centroid is the average of the mesh faces' centers, weighted by their area. How can I do this in Python (but not necessarily using Blender's Python API)?

Comment: Your description is exactly how I'd go about it, even though I've never had to do this before. Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: @MarkRansom I would say computing the area of the triangles and the last step to get the centroid point. I'm not entirely sure about the final normalization step.

Comment: Questions on this site get a lot more attention when you demonstrate at least a *little* understanding and effort. Nobody wants to do all your work for you. Edit the question to show the parts you've figured out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let define each triangle with 3 vertexes `p0,p1,p2` the center is easy

```
center = (p0+p1+p2) /3
```

it is just the average of all vertices which forms it. The area can be computed by cross product as:

```
area = 0.5 * | (p1-p0) x (p2-p0) |
area = 0.5 * length(cross( p1-p0, p2-p0 ))
```

Both are the same just in different notation... So the centroid you are describing should be computed like this (in **C++**):

```cpp
float area_sum=0.0;
vec3 centroid=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
for (int i=0;i<triangles;i++)
 {
 t = triangle[i];
 vec3  center = (t.p0+t.p1+t.p2) /3; 
 float area = 0.5 * length(cross(t.p1-t.p0, t.p2-t.p0));
 centroid += area*center;
 area_sum += area;
 }
centroid /= area_sum;
```

where `triangle[trianges]` is array of your faces where each face has `p0,p1,p2` as **3D** vectors. Sorry I do not use **Python** so you need to adapt the vector math to your style/environment. If you do not know how to compute cross product look here:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

vector math is at the bottom ...

Answer (score 5):

Note that Spektre's answer gives the centroid of the *surface area* of the mesh, which might be what you want.

If you want the center of the mesh *volume* instead (like a center of mass assuming constant density), you would need to do the following:

1. Create a tetrahedron from each triangle using the 3 vertices of the triangle plus the origin point.
2. Calculate the signed volume and center for each tetrahedron
3. Total up the volumes and the volume-weighted centers
4. Get the mesh center by dividing the sum of the volume-weighted centers by the total volume

Pseudocode:

```
meshVolume = 0
temp = (0,0,0)

for each triangle in mesh (with vertices v1, v2, v3)
  center = (v1 + v2 + v3) / 4          // center of tetrahedron
  volume = dot(v1, cross(v2, v3)) / 6  // signed volume of tetrahedron
  meshVolume += volume
  temp += center * volume

meshCenter = temp / totalVolume
```

Comment: Is it supposed be `temp += center * volume`? I can't figure out why it would be `temp = center * volume`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Fixed it now.